# RxJava2 concatArrayEagerDelayError doesn't load cached data when an error is thorwn on request to get remote data

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-room

I am using the below code in an Android project to load data from the database(cache) and from API request:

```
Observable.concatArrayEagerDelayError(
    getDatabaseData(),
    getRemoteData()
).debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Both returns from `getDatabaseData()` and `getRemoteData()` are `Observable<MyObj>`

It looks like is working as expected, except when an error occurs while trying to get the remote data.
On the subscriber, I receive just the onError callback, so the cached data is not available to be handled and displayed.

I tried changing to `concatArray` and `concat`, but it has the same issue.

Any possible solution to this problem?

Comment: Try without debounce. Errors in debounce will skip ahead of items. You could also do `materialize().debounce().dematerialize(v -> v)` to hide the error from it.

Comment: Without the debounce works. But I need it to prevent UI flicker since this code is inside a Timer. About the second option, with materialize, it has the same effect as using only debounce.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the error will push out the database value in `debounce` thus it is never delivered. If one materializes the flow, then the error notification will do the same.

The best I can think of is to shift the error beyond the debounce timer thus you get the succeeding item at least:

```java
Observable.concatArrayEagerDelayError(
        Observable.just(1).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
        Observable.<Integer>error(new IOException()).delay(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true)
)
.onErrorResumeNext((Function<Throwable, Observable<Integer>>)(error -> 
     Observable.<Integer>error(error).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true))
)
.doOnEach(System.out::println)
.debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.blockingSubscribe(
        System.out::println,
        Throwable::printStackTrace
);
```